# How to avoid VideoJoin function changing the playback speed?

Tags: video, join

VideoJoin changed the video speed of all elements in the resultant video.  All elements of the argument list to VideoJoin were of the same file format. I tried changing the number of video files $n$ in the argument list which may provide a hint to an error. When viewing the output file the contained videos run faster than their input element files. With two input files the video runs for half the output file duration and the last frame is output for the last half of the output file. With $n$ input files the output file runs at $n$ times the speed of each input file. The last frame is visible from $1/n$ to $n/n$ of that total duration.  The total duration is correct.

The mp4 Video file Information is Video Tracks OriginalRasterSize {730,480}, VideoEncoding H264, BitDepth 8, ColorSpace RGB, FrameRate 30.00 frames/s, and same Audio Tracks AudioEncoding AAC, AudioChannels 2, AudioBitDepth 32, SampleRate 44100 samples/s.

Here is the statement I used,

```
VideoJoin[videoLst, FrameRate -> 30]
```

What could I have possibly done wrong?

This is my first post. I've since improved the wording. Please forgive any errors in formatting. Thanks to @creidhne for correcting the format of my first post.

Comment: Have you tried using the SampleRate option as well? You can always slow down any resultant video by using the `VideoTimeStretch` function as well. Kindly see the Documentation for the details.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  Let me explain further. I was taking video segments off a camcorder using <code>VideoCapture</code>.  Then joining segments using <code>VideoJoin</code>. The outcome had the peculiar nature described above that the joined video played faster than the video segment files and  when they finished the last slide was shown to the expected file duration.

Comment: Further investigation revealed that indeed the problem is not with <code>VideoCapture</code> at all.  <code>Information[recordedvideofile]</code> had the FrameRate at 30 fps, whereas MediaPlayer yields FrameRate=~8 fps.   I'm at a loss to explain why and don't know how to further diagnose within Mathematica.

Comment: I'm also struggling with getting the editing correct on these posts. Can someone please point me to documentation on that? Thankyou.